# invalid header error on sending a request with curl

Tags: php, curl

here is my code

```
echo 22;
$url = 'http://www.10bet.com/pagemethods.aspx/GetLeaguesContent';

$fields = array(    
        'BranchID' => urlencode('1') , 
        'LeaguesCollection' => urlencode('10098') , 
                );

$fields_string  = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump( $result );
```

i keep getting

```
Bad Request - Invalid Header

HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are surprisingly getting the error

```
Bad Request - Invalid Header

HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.
```

Because you use an invalid header name :)

You use

```
Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Notice the **space** in the header name

The correct usage would be:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone hit this as described by [@ZombieSpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22241043/6462207), and wonder where this strictness comes about, this is as defined in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2, as follows:

```
3.2.  Header Fields

   Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed
   by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
   optional trailing whitespace.
```